# Deleting item and deleting from "balance" - (React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to add deleting method which works like: when I click on the button, it deletes the Item and redudes balance by deleted Item expense amount.

So my question is, how to change the "balance" method to way that it reduces the balance by deleted Item expense amount.

Error message:

[image: 1]

The application:

[image: 2]

**App.js** - Inside there is "balance" method

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Form from "./components/Form.js";
import List from "./components/List.js"
import Alert from "./components/Alert.js"

function App() {
  const initialExpenses = [
    { id: Math.random() * 100000, description: "Example", amount: 0, SelectedCategory: [""] },
  ];

  const [expenses, setExpeneses] = useState(initialExpenses);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({show: false});
  const [SelectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState([]);
  

  const handleDescription = e => {
    setDescription(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleAmount = e => {
    setAmount(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleCategory = e => {
    setSelectedCategory(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(amount > 0 || description !== "") {
      var singleExpenses = {id: Math.random() * 100000, description, amount, SelectedCategory}
      setExpeneses([...expenses, singleExpenses]);
      setAmount("");
      setDescription("");
      handleAlert({text: "Added"});
    } else {
      handleAlert({text: "Value cannot be empty"});
    }
  }

  const handleAlert = ({ text }) => {
    setAlert({show: true, text});
    setTimeout(() => {setAlert({show: false})}, 2000)
  }

  return (
    <>
      {alert.show && <Alert text={alert.text} />}
      <Alert />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Your balance: </h3> // Balance method inside this div
          <span>{expenses.reduce((previous, current) => {return (previous += parseInt(current.amount));}, 0)}$</span>
        </div>
        <Form amount={amount}
              description={description} 
              SelectedCategory={SelectedCategory}
              handleAmount={handleAmount} 
              handleDescription={handleDescription}
              handleCategory={handleCategory} 
              handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
      </div>
      <List expenses={expenses}
             setExpeneses={setExpeneses}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**List.js** - Handling delete

```
import React from 'react';
import Item from './Item.js';

const List = ({ expenses, setExpeneses } ) => {

  const handleDelete = expense => {
    console.log({expense});
    const newExpanse = expenses.filter(item => item.id !== expense.id)
    setExpeneses({newExpanse});
  }

  return (
    <>
        { expenses.map((expense) => {
            return (
              <Item expense={expense} 
                    key={expense.id}
                    handleDelete={handleDelete(expense)}
                    setExpeneses={setExpeneses}/>
            );
          })} 
    </>


  );
  
}
export default List;
```

**Item.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Item = ({ expense: { id, description, amount, SelectedCategory }, handleDelete }) => {
  return (
    <div class="list">
      <tr>
        <td>{amount}$</td>
        <td>{SelectedCategory}</td>
        <td>{description}</td> 
        <button class="delete_button" onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
      </tr>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are two problems here. The first is with the way you call `handleDelete` and the second is with the way `handleDelete` calls `setExpenses`.

For the first problem, you're calling `handleDelete` when you pass it as a prop to the `<Item>` component. So `handleDelete` gets called for each item on each render, rather than when clicked. To fix this update your code to pass a function, rather than the output of the `handleDelete` function, like this:

```js
<Item expense={expense} 
    key={expense.id}
    handleDelete={() => handleDelete(expense)}
    setExpeneses={setExpeneses}
/>
```

The second issue is that you call `setExpeneses` like this: `setExpeneses({newExpanse})`, which sets the value of `expenses` to `{newExpanse: [...]}`, which is an object, not an array, thus `expenses.reduce` is not a function (as the error you're getting states). You can fix this by just removing the curly braces and simply calling like this: `setExpeneses(newExpanse)`.